# Calculate time difference in java

Tags: java

I want to calculate time difference in java. I am calculating successfully only in between 1 hour. When I enter the time above 1 hour calculation is getting Wrong.

```
String start= "12:00:00";
    String end= "12:50:00";
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    Date date1 = format.parse(start);
    Date date2 = format.parse(end);
    long difference = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
    System.out.println(difference/1000);

    double time = difference/1000;

    double tot = time/60;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, tot);
```

result displayed 50mins successfully from above code

I modified the same code and it looks like this:

```
String start = "12:00:00";
    String end = "01:50:00";
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    Date date1 = format.parse(start);
    Date date2 = format.parse(end);
    long difference = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
    System.out.println(difference/1000);

    double time = difference/1000;

    double tot = time/60;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, tot);
```

here result displayed

-610.0 I don't know why I need to display the output of 1.50

Comment: Yes, 10 before two in the morning is before noon - what are you thinking?

Comment: Is the requirement for this to work with both 24hr and 12hr formats? Or do you want to stick to 12hr format? Do you plan to ad AM/PM identifiers?

Comment: yes  Piro says Reinstate Monica

Comment: The time that you have is 24hr. 1:50 is before 12 so it should be a negative value

Answer (score 0):

Because you input the time in the AM|PM form, but your code is supposed to work with the 24-hour time format.
Change the time from

```
String end = "01:50:00";
```

to

```
String end = "13:50:00";
```

and it will work like a charm :)
(Or you can change the code to work with AM-PM time model, but it will be more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I would use the new OffsetTime classes to solve this problem.

Here is some example code:

```
public static  void distance(String strTime1, String strTime2) {
    OffsetTime time1 = OffsetTime.parse(strTime1);
    OffsetTime time2 = OffsetTime.parse(strTime2);

    int time1Seconds = time1.get(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_DAY);
    int time2Seconds = time2.get(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_DAY);

    System.out.println("Time 1 in seconds: " + time1Seconds);
    System.out.println("Time 1 in seconds: " + time2Seconds);
    System.out.println("Distance: " + Math.abs(time1Seconds - time2Seconds));
}
```

What you are doing is to parse a String simliar to yours. As a difference, I would recommend you to always add timezone information. Since it probably doesn't matter much in your case, I'd just add +00:00.

Please not Maths.abs(). As long as you are interested in the distance between both times and not in which direction the distance is, you can use this to get rid of minus or plus prefixes and use the absolute value.

That way you can create OffsetTime by parsing this string. After that you can read the minute of the day.

Please try it with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    distance("10:00:00+00:00", "12:00:00+00:00");
    distance("12:30:00+00:00", "12:31:00+00:00");
    distance("12:31:00+00:00", "12:30:00+00:00");
}
```

The results would be:

```
Time 1 in seconds: 600
Time 1 in seconds: 720
Distance: 120
Time 1 in seconds: 750
Time 1 in seconds: 751
Distance: 1
Time 1 in seconds: 751
Time 1 in seconds: 750
Distance: 1
```

You mentioned that you need fractions of minutes, like 1.5. Fractions are always complicated and not precise. That's why people invented BigDecimal. However, in your case BigDecimal doesn't help. I would recommend you to use a smaller unit, like seconds.

Just change your code to:

```
    int time1Seconds = time1.get(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_DAY);
    int time2Seconds = time2.get(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_DAY);
```

Here is some Javadocs:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/time/LocalDateTime.html

And a tutorial to the new classes (JDK8):
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/timezones.html

Answer (score -1):

From [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

> Letter |   Date or Time Component
>   H | Hour in day (0-23) .
>   h | Hour in am/pm (1-12)

So in your case you have `"HH:mm:ss"` which stands for 24Hr time format.
and its start from 00:00 till `23:59`

So you can change this to like below for above pattern:

```
String start = "12:00:00";
String end = "13:50:00";
```

Or you can change your pattern like below:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
String start = "12:00:00";
String end = "01:50:00";
```

See result: [code output](https://paiza.io/projects/GC-wIeWq5dNMhqVviFDVIg)

Comment: and get the currect answer

Comment: @Javafiver sry answer didn't got posted fully. Updated